# Socket.IO not working properly

Tags: html, node.js, socket.io

for some reason my server that uses socket.io is not working properly. The program makes a HTML5 canvas and then opens sockets so that multiple people can view one canvas. I can get the canvas to draw stuff accordingly to input, however I can't get the socket.io to run correctly so that browsers synchronize the drawings. I am running this on ec2. Any help is appreciated:)

I wrote the server in node.js

server.js
http://pastebin.com/hH51DTb3

index.html
http://pastebin.com/b7PrScze

scripts.js
http://pastebin.com/zLgDf7zs

Oh, and btw you can view what it looks like here: http://107.20.163.241/

EDIT: Yes KaoD of course I have tried things. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling socket.io, I've tried moving the project folder to different directory locations, I've tried moving the socket.io to an external folder, and a few others that I can't seem to remember atm

Minimum test case is if both people go to the same site, they will both in real time see each other draw

CHANGING THE SECURITY GROUP WORKED, THANK YOU.

Comment: Do you have the AWS security group configured to allow connections on port 4000?

Comment: So what's going on besides "it's not working"? Have you tried ANYTHING?

Comment: Could you reduce this to a minimal test case you can include in your question?  If/when those links change or go stale, this question won't be of help to future users.

Comment: have you checked the socket successfully connecting in firebug?

Comment: where is the client side socket.io script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my security group was not configured to allow port 4000. Thanks to fourk for suggesting the fix.

Comment: i was using port 4000 too. how do i check the "Security group"? what do you mean by that exactly?